# tf.py_func() unexpected outputs in loop using lambda function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am observing diverging behaviour from both Numpy and pure Tensorflow when implementing the same simple functionality that shares a variable across iterations in a for loop with [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func).

Let's start with the pure Numpy version:

```
def my_func(x, k):
    return np.tile(x,k)

x = np.ones((1), np.int64)
for i in range(1,3):
    x = my_func(x, i)

print(x)
```

This produces the expected output. Initially `x` is `[1]`. On the first iteration, it is replicated once to produce `[1]`. Then on the next iteration, the result is replicated twice, producing the final output `[1 1]`.

A similar approach also produces the same expected output in pure Tensorflow:

```
x = tf.constant([1], tf.int64)
for i in range(1,3):
    x = tf.tile(x, [i])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    xx = sess.run(x)
    print(xx)
```

The output is `[1 1]`.

Now I am attempting to do essentially the same thing using [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func), and I can't wrap my head around why I am seeing a different output. This code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def my_func(x, k):
    return np.tile(x,k)

x = tf.constant([1], tf.int64)
for i in range(1,3):
    x = tf.py_func(lambda y: my_func(y, i), [x], tf.int64)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    xx = sess.run(x)
    print(xx)
```

Produces the unexpected result `[1 1 1 1]`.

Why is this happening? Does `py_func` have some property that it does not work well with sharing (tensor) variable names, in this case the variable `x` that is updated on each loop iteration?

Please note that this is a simplified example that reproduces the problem, and whose functionality is easy to reproduce in pure Tensorflow. In my actual application there is a need to use `tf.py_func`, since the functionality is more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the lambda function, it works as intended:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def my_func(x, k):
    return np.tile(x,k)

x = tf.constant([1], tf.int64)
for i in range(1,3):
    x = tf.py_func(my_func, [x, i], tf.int64)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    xx = sess.run(x)
    print(xx)
```

returns `[1 1]`

**edit**

I found out why: `lambda y: my_func(y, i)` saves i by reference and not by value. Therefore the last i value of the for loop is applied to all `py_func` in the loop. Here is a simpler example that shows the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def my_func(x, y):
  return x - y

x1 = tf.constant([0], tf.float32)
for i in range(2):
    x1 = tf.py_func(lambda y: my_func(y, i), [x1], tf.float32)

x2 = tf.constant([0], tf.float32)
x2 = tf.py_func(lambda y: my_func(y, 0), [x2], tf.float32)
x2 = tf.py_func(lambda y: my_func(y, 1), [x2], tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(x1))
    print(sess.run(x2))
```

Comment: Nice job! This one really had me scratching my head.